# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'managers.id' in 'on clause' in Laravel 5 Many-to-Many relationship query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many

I am new to laravel. I am working on this laravel 5 app and I got stuck here.

I have two eloquent models

```
class Manager extends Eloquent{

    public function supervisors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Supervisor')->withTimestamps();
    }

}

class Supervisor extends Eloquent {

    public function managers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Manager');
    }
}
```

Manager and Supervisor are related by a many to many relationship. I have followed the laravel 5 documentation and created my tables as expected.

e.g 
Manager Table Structure

- user_id PK ( FK from a User table (references id))
- grade

Supervisor Table Structure

- user_id PK ( FK from a User table (references id) )
- excellence

Pivot Table Structure (manager_supervisor)

- manager_id PK  (FK from Manager Table (references user_id))
- supervisor_id PK (FK from Supervisor Table (references user_id))

When I execute the following query, the result is not as expected

```
 $user = App\User::find(2);
 $user->supervisor->managers;
```

Sample Result:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'managers.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `managers`.*, `manager_supervisor`.`supervisor_id` as `pivot_supervisor_id`, `manager_supervisor`.`manager_id` as `pivot_manager_id` from `managers` inner join `manager_supervisor` on `managers`.`id` = `manager_supervisor`.`manager_id` where `manager_supervisor`.`supervisor_id` is null)'
```

I was expecting the 'on clause' to return something like

```
managers`.`user_id` = `manager_supervisor`.`manager_id` where `manager_supervisor`.`supervisor_id` is 2
```

What are my missing here? What can really be wrong?

Comment: This is a bit tricky, because I personally would not set my tables up this way. However, Laravel looks for primary keys to be called `id` so if you are using a primary key with a different name you will need to set the primary key inside your model: `$primaryKey='user_id'`;

Comment: Thank you so much @craig_h. Adding the variable works. I am beginning to experience unnecessary complexity for organizing my tables as such. It is an inheritance with a table per class. How would you suggest I organize my tables?

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do was set a primary variable in both models:

```
class Manager extends Eloquent{

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    public function supervisors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Supervisor')->withTimestamps();
    }

}

class Supervisor extends Eloquent {

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    public function managers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Manager');
    }
}
```